# MongoDB 2.4 authenticating to MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, database

I am trying to have my raspberry pi (which from what I can tell from research only can support MongoDB 2.4) write to our database, which is hosted by mlab, and I can only seem to get it to use Mongo 3.2. When I use my raspberry pi to connect to the database it says authentication failed. Other posts say it is because 2.4 doesn't work with 3.2. Does anyone know how to make them work together or to get them to be the matching versions? 
Thank you!

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the database? Are you using the mongo shell or an application driver?

Comment: Im using the Mongo Shell

Answer (score 0):

The "authentication failed" message is due to a change in MongoDB 3.0; the authentication mechanism was changed to [SCRAM-SHA1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers). This means that the mongo shell utilities from 2.6 and earlier will fail to authenticate against deployments using this new mechanism.

You may want to try using the 32-bit linux version of MongoDB 3.0 or 3.2 (https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community). Click "Previous Releases" --> Linux --> Version --> 32 bit version. Note: I haven't tested this myself, so it may not work as expected.

Alternatively, you may want to try connection using a **SCRAM-SHA-1** compatible [application driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers).